# ¿Como puedo adaptar las siguientes funciones a un programa de c++?

Tags: c++

estoy en desarrollando un programa en el lenguaje c++.Antan todas las funciones, tanto agregar_inicio, agregar_final, quitar_inicio, quitar_final, mostrar, y salir.Los que no andan son agregar_despues_de y agregar_antes_de.Que ya estan adaptadas en el switch del int main.

A continuacion: (agregar_antes_de).

```
void agregar_antes_de(tlista lis, pnodo nuevo)
{pnodo p;
if(lis.inicio==NULL)
{
lis.inicio=nuevo;
lis.fin=nuevo;

}  
else
{   for(p=lis.inicio->sig;p!=lis.fin && p->dato!=valor;p=p->sig)
//for(p=lis.inicio->sig;p!=nuevo;p=p->sig)
nuevo->ant=lis.fin;
lis.fin->sig=nuevo;
lis.fin->ant=nuevo;     
}
else{
cout<<"error"<<endl;
}
//lis.inicio->ant=lis.fin;
//  lis.fin->sig=lis.inicio;
}
```

quisiera poder adaptar esta funcion para que ande.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Amigo, es la segunda publicacion con este codigo. Necesitamos que nos digas cual es el comportamiento esperado, cual es el comportamiento que obtienes. Entradas para tener como ejemplo, y sobre todo, codigo que solo pueda pegar en mi editor y que corra para ver el problema. De la forma en la que esta la pregunta, que ni incluye lo que quieres que haga el codigo, no podemos ayudarte.